# How to make the body and it's children have 100% of the visible height?

Tags: html, css

**BOTH HTML/BODY 100% SOLUTION**

```
html, body { height : 100% }
```

This works, no doubt. Both elements will take up the full screen, perfect.

Why not use? vh-instead? Well that has to do with mobile Safari, there is a big difference between 100% taking up the visible space and 100vh taking the view height making it larger then the toolbar, not desired in my case.

There is just one big problem with this approach. If the content within the body takes up more then 100% of the visible height, like in most cases, it will overflow. This might not be a big problem, besides it feeling hacky, however it does break -webkit-sticky to not stick elements further then the body container.

**MIN-HEIGHT TO THE RESCUE, NOT QUITE**

So actually what we want is to say, hey `HTML` and `BODY` be at least 100%. That would solve all our problems because that's exactly what we want. Luckily there is a property for that `min-height`.

```
html, body { min-height : 100% }
```

If they are both at least 100% of the viewport it should work, but it doesn't.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

```
html {
    height : 100%;
}

body {
    min-height : 100%;
}
```

This does make the height of the body the viewport height, however all the children elements do not recognize this, for example:

**HTML Source**

```
<head>
  <title>Body Height Problem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullheight-cover">
    Some beautiful image with the CSS background.
  </div>

  <section class="content">
   Some content in section A.
  </section>

  <section class="content">
   Some content in section B.
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS Source**

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.fullheight-cover {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

(Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbGWBq)

If you inspect the elements you will notice that the body will now have a height, which is awesome. However you expect `.fullheight-cover` to fill up this space with it's height being minimal 100% as well, but this does not work.

How can I make it so that the children of the body can make use of the 100% height that flows naturally?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Im added `display: flex` to `body`, and `width: 100%` to `.content`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Body Height Problem</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    Some sample content.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does give the content a 100% height but a few problems with this tactic. A) I wrote content as an example the full code would include more elements. if I change the flex direction to column to show the elements, the height breaks again. B) The body looses his static rendering advantage.

Comment: Just use `display: flex` for `.content` and for `body` and `flex-direction: column` for `.content`.

Comment: What u see advantage of static rendering? 2016 year - responsive all around.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I can help you with a solution 
you can fix this template with css alone, Its better to use css rather than js.

This is a sample template please go through it.

**SOLUTION**

The html is..

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <body>
    <header class="border"><h1>Header</h1></header>
    <section class="sub-header border"><h2>Sub header</h2></section>
    <div class="side-menu border">
      <div class="menu-head"><h3>Menu heading</h3></div>
    <div class="menu-items ">
        <p>Menu items 1</p>
        <p>Menu items 2</p>
        <p>Menu items 3</p>
        <p>Menu items 4</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="main-content border">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rhoncus in nulla eget congue, lacus at id libero. Wisi viverra eget luctus senectus, nibh in at non tincidunt leo nulla, cras non risus, tincidunt vitae egestas. Condimentum integer sem at porttitor mi parturient. Amet vivamus nulla vivamus, dignissim velit ut quis erat donec. Tellus amet augue sodales ante. Nisl vehicula sollicitudin vitae. Ipsum arcu nulla elit maecenas habitasse, et mi, vehicula ullamcorper, nec eu eget ac placerat. In ac mauris morbi. Interdum nec tincidunt at ipsum est elit. Senectus lectus tincidunt aenean, nunc non vitae velit, ante sagittis animi vestibulum vestibulum luctus proin, fringilla quis nobis nunc ligula mus, vitae laoreet. Integer donec imperdiet vehicula.
Lectus mauris aliquam a mus consequat. Pulvinar minus in nam, aliquet erat, habitasse sed lorem velit, nullam purus in pariatur vitae lobortis sit. Varius et, erat nec dapibus tellus massa vitae, facilisis nulla pulvinar vivamus, nascetur imperdiet velit volutpat ut tellus. Pretium eros nascetur wisi consequat, pulvinar suspendisse duis curae, ratione a est sollicitudin maecenas sit mus, suspendisse justo lectus vitae libero est. Luctus ultricies, dis praesent in vestibulum, scelerisque ligula massa fusce, metus hendrerit vitae vitae rhoncus, arcu morbi ipsum curabitur dolor. Mauris vitae in, viverra amet lacus metus in mollis at. Lorem quam elementum mauris nam placerat. Urna in iaculis morbi lectus mauris vivamus.
Libero corporis amet, ante justo et pede arcu, ipsum massa ridiculus, semper class accumsan sociis cras. Dui eget vel ligula vel felis in. Massa mollis etiam gravida sagittis ante ligula, dis vehicula, sit leo, convallis morbi eu dis nec sapien sapien, augue imperdiet cursus justo conubia turpis. Nunc molestie pellentesque, phasellus scelerisque, in tristique et vel, adipisci dis pharetra nunc lacus. Rhoncus mi faucibus erat. Nibh nam, nunc vestibulum sed pellentesque suscipit exercitation, elit consectetuer vitae dolor sapien lorem, ligula vestibulum justo ut. Mauris urna est metus vel id sed, ornare condimentum, neque magna sodales, illum adipiscing tristique ligula augue vel, ut minus et pretium enim perspiciatis ullamcorper.
Erat eu cubilia massa arcu etiam, duis nostra sodales dictum scelerisque sed, fringilla pretium elementum nibh ligula, justo hendrerit magna. Dolor tellus cras, amet at aliquam egestas non tincidunt, vitae quis posuere consequat, purus massa sodales. Vulputate ipsum nec. Vitae amet, a massa mauris et, egestas odio fermentum, nam augue ipsum, id penatibus arcu ridiculus arcu. Nibh aenean sit, est quis luctus, eu eget consequat sit tincidunt a wisi, wisi eu, mi lacus maecenas. In consectetuer elementum, velit condimentum viverra porta. Arcu vulputate, elit vivamus ut sem vulputate, odio ac ipsum aliquam ut semper ante, ac ut ultricies ac, nec arcu risus dignissim fermentum pede amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rhoncus in nulla eget congue, lacus at id libero. Wisi viverra eget luctus senectus, nibh in at non tincidunt leo nulla, cras non risus, tincidunt vitae egestas. Condimentum integer sem at porttitor mi parturient. Amet vivamus nulla vivamus, dignissim velit ut quis erat donec. Tellus amet augue sodales ante. Nisl vehicula sollicitudin vitae. Ipsum arcu nulla elit maecenas habitasse, et mi, vehicula ullamcorper, nec eu eget ac placerat. In ac mauris morbi. Interdum nec tincidunt at ipsum est elit. Senectus lectus tincidunt aenean, nunc non vitae velit, ante sagittis animi vestibulum vestibulum luctus proin, fringilla quis nobis nunc ligula mus, vitae laoreet. Integer donec imperdiet vehicula.
Lectus mauris aliquam a mus consequat. Pulvinar minus in nam, aliquet erat, habitasse sed lorem velit, nullam purus in pariatur vitae lobortis sit. Varius et, erat nec dapibus tellus massa vitae, facilisis nulla pulvinar vivamus, nascetur imperdiet velit volutpat ut tellus. Pretium eros nascetur wisi consequat, pulvinar suspendisse duis curae, ratione a est sollicitudin maecenas sit mus, suspendisse justo lectus vitae libero est. Luctus ultricies, dis praesent in vestibulum, scelerisque ligula massa fusce, metus hendrerit vitae vitae rhoncus, arcu morbi ipsum curabitur dolor. Mauris vitae in, viverra amet lacus metus in mollis at. Lorem quam elementum mauris nam placerat. Urna in iaculis morbi lectus mauris vivamus.
Libero corporis amet, ante justo et pede arcu, ipsum massa ridiculus, semper class accumsan sociis cras. Dui eget vel ligula vel felis in. Massa mollis etiam gravida sagittis ante ligula, dis vehicula, sit leo, convallis morbi eu dis nec sapien sapien, augue imperdiet cursus justo conubia turpis. Nunc molestie pellentesque, phasellus scelerisque, in tristique et vel, adipisci dis pharetra nunc lacus. Rhoncus mi faucibus erat. Nibh nam, nunc vestibulum sed pellentesque suscipit exercitation, elit consectetuer vitae dolor sapien lorem, ligula vestibulum justo ut. Mauris urna est metus vel id sed, ornare condimentum, neque magna sodales, illum adipiscing tristique ligula augue vel, ut minus et pretium enim perspiciatis ullamcorper.
Erat eu cubilia massa arcu etiam, duis nostra sodales dictum scelerisque sed, fringilla pretium elementum nibh ligula, justo hendrerit magna. Dolor tellus cras, amet at aliquam egestas non tincidunt, vitae quis posuere consequat, purus massa sodales. Vulputate ipsum nec. Vitae amet, a massa mauris et, egestas odio fermentum, nam augue ipsum, id penatibus arcu ridiculus arcu. Nibh aenean sit, est quis luctus, eu eget consequat sit tincidunt a wisi, wisi eu, mi lacus maecenas. In consectetuer elementum, velit condimentum viverra porta. Arcu vulputate, elit vivamus ut sem vulputate, odio ac ipsum aliquam ut semper ante, ac ut ultricies ac, nec arcu risus dignissim fermentum pede amet.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS is..

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.border{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
header{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ea4242;
}
.sub-header{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 39px;
    width: 100%; 
    background: #d46b6b;
}
.side-menu{
width: 240px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 68px;
    height: 89%;


}
.menu-head{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background: #96a2ff;
}
.menu-items{
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-items p{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #777; 
}
.main-content{
    height: 1900px;
    width: calc(100% - 252px);
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-top: 66px;
    background: #fdefa9;
    padding: 0 0px 0 10px;    
}
```

Try this it will suits you the best way

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.border{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
header{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ea4242;
}
.sub-header{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 39px;
    width: 100%; 
    background: #d46b6b;
}
.side-menu{
width: 240px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 68px;
    height: 89%;
    overflow:auto;
overflow:auto;

    
}
.menu-head{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background: #96a2ff;
}
.menu-items{
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-items p{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #777; 
}
.main-content{
    height: 1900px;
    width: calc(100% - 252px);
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-top: 66px;
    background: #fdefa9;
    padding: 0 0px 0 10px;    
}
```

```html
<header class="border"><h1>Header</h1></header>
    <section class="sub-header border"><h2>Sub header</h2></section>
    <div class="side-menu border">
      <div class="menu-head"><h3>Menu heading</h3></div>
    <div class="menu-items ">
        <p>Menu items 1</p>
        <p>Menu items 2</p>
        <p>Menu items 3</p>
        <p>Menu items 4</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="main-content border">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rhoncus in nulla eget congue, lacus at id libero. Wisi viverra eget luctus senectus, nibh in at non tincidunt leo nulla, cras non risus, tincidunt vitae egestas. Condimentum integer sem at porttitor mi parturient. Amet vivamus nulla vivamus, dignissim velit ut quis erat donec. Tellus amet augue sodales ante. Nisl vehicula sollicitudin vitae. Ipsum arcu nulla elit maecenas habitasse, et mi, vehicula ullamcorper, nec eu eget ac placerat. In ac mauris morbi. Interdum nec tincidunt at ipsum est elit. Senectus lectus tincidunt aenean, nunc non vitae velit, ante sagittis animi vestibulum vestibulum luctus proin, fringilla quis nobis nunc ligula mus, vitae laoreet. Integer donec imperdiet vehicula.
Lectus mauris aliquam a mus consequat. Pulvinar minus in nam, aliquet erat, habitasse sed lorem velit, nullam purus in pariatur vitae lobortis sit. Varius et, erat nec dapibus tellus massa vitae, facilisis nulla pulvinar vivamus, nascetur imperdiet velit volutpat ut tellus. Pretium eros nascetur wisi consequat, pulvinar suspendisse duis curae, ratione a est sollicitudin maecenas sit mus, suspendisse justo lectus vitae libero est. Luctus ultricies, dis praesent in vestibulum, scelerisque ligula massa fusce, metus hendrerit vitae vitae rhoncus, arcu morbi ipsum curabitur dolor. Mauris vitae in, viverra amet lacus metus in mollis at. Lorem quam elementum mauris nam placerat. Urna in iaculis morbi lectus mauris vivamus.
Libero corporis amet, ante justo et pede arcu, ipsum massa ridiculus, semper class accumsan sociis cras. Dui eget vel ligula vel felis in. Massa mollis etiam gravida sagittis ante ligula, dis vehicula, sit leo, convallis morbi eu dis nec sapien sapien, augue imperdiet cursus justo conubia turpis. Nunc molestie pellentesque, phasellus scelerisque, in tristique et vel, adipisci dis pharetra nunc lacus. Rhoncus mi faucibus erat. Nibh nam, nunc vestibulum sed pellentesque suscipit exercitation, elit consectetuer vitae dolor sapien lorem, ligula vestibulum justo ut. Mauris urna est metus vel id sed, ornare condimentum, neque magna sodales, illum adipiscing tristique ligula augue vel, ut minus et pretium enim perspiciatis ullamcorper.
Erat eu cubilia massa arcu etiam, duis nostra sodales dictum scelerisque sed, fringilla pretium elementum nibh ligula, justo hendrerit magna. Dolor tellus cras, amet at aliquam egestas non tincidunt, vitae quis posuere consequat, purus massa sodales. Vulputate ipsum nec. Vitae amet, a massa mauris et, egestas odio fermentum, nam augue ipsum, id penatibus arcu ridiculus arcu. Nibh aenean sit, est quis luctus, eu eget consequat sit tincidunt a wisi, wisi eu, mi lacus maecenas. In consectetuer elementum, velit condimentum viverra porta. Arcu vulputate, elit vivamus ut sem vulputate, odio ac ipsum aliquam ut semper ante, ac ut ultricies ac, nec arcu risus dignissim fermentum pede amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rhoncus in nulla eget congue, lacus at id libero. Wisi viverra eget luctus senectus, nibh in at non tincidunt leo nulla, cras non risus, tincidunt vitae egestas. Condimentum integer sem at porttitor mi parturient. Amet vivamus nulla vivamus, dignissim velit ut quis erat donec. Tellus amet augue sodales ante. Nisl vehicula sollicitudin vitae. Ipsum arcu nulla elit maecenas habitasse, et mi, vehicula ullamcorper, nec eu eget ac placerat. In ac mauris morbi. Interdum nec tincidunt at ipsum est elit. Senectus lectus tincidunt aenean, nunc non vitae velit, ante sagittis animi vestibulum vestibulum luctus proin, fringilla quis nobis nunc ligula mus, vitae laoreet. Integer donec imperdiet vehicula.
Lectus mauris aliquam a mus consequat. Pulvinar minus in nam, aliquet erat, habitasse sed lorem velit, nullam purus in pariatur vitae lobortis sit. Varius et, erat nec dapibus tellus massa vitae, facilisis nulla pulvinar vivamus, nascetur imperdiet velit volutpat ut tellus. Pretium eros nascetur wisi consequat, pulvinar suspendisse duis curae, ratione a est sollicitudin maecenas sit mus, suspendisse justo lectus vitae libero est. Luctus ultricies, dis praesent in vestibulum, scelerisque ligula massa fusce, metus hendrerit vitae vitae rhoncus, arcu morbi ipsum curabitur dolor. Mauris vitae in, viverra amet lacus metus in mollis at. Lorem quam elementum mauris nam placerat. Urna in iaculis morbi lectus mauris vivamus.
Libero corporis amet, ante justo et pede arcu, ipsum massa ridiculus, semper class accumsan sociis cras. Dui eget vel ligula vel felis in. Massa mollis etiam gravida sagittis ante ligula, dis vehicula, sit leo, convallis morbi eu dis nec sapien sapien, augue imperdiet cursus justo conubia turpis. Nunc molestie pellentesque, phasellus scelerisque, in tristique et vel, adipisci dis pharetra nunc lacus. Rhoncus mi faucibus erat. Nibh nam, nunc vestibulum sed pellentesque suscipit exercitation, elit consectetuer vitae dolor sapien lorem, ligula vestibulum justo ut. Mauris urna est metus vel id sed, ornare condimentum, neque magna sodales, illum adipiscing tristique ligula augue vel, ut minus et pretium enim perspiciatis ullamcorper.
Erat eu cubilia massa arcu etiam, duis nostra sodales dictum scelerisque sed, fringilla pretium elementum nibh ligula, justo hendrerit magna. Dolor tellus cras, amet at aliquam egestas non tincidunt, vitae quis posuere consequat, purus massa sodales. Vulputate ipsum nec. Vitae amet, a massa mauris et, egestas odio fermentum, nam augue ipsum, id penatibus arcu ridiculus arcu. Nibh aenean sit, est quis luctus, eu eget consequat sit tincidunt a wisi, wisi eu, mi lacus maecenas. In consectetuer elementum, velit condimentum viverra porta. Arcu vulputate, elit vivamus ut sem vulputate, odio ac ipsum aliquam ut semper ante, ac ut ultricies ac, nec arcu risus dignissim fermentum pede amet.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<div style="background: green; float: left; padding-bottom: 20000px; margin-bottom: -20000px; width: 30%">Column 1st</div>
<div style="background: red; padding-bottom: 20000px; margin-bottom: -20000px; float: left; width:70%">Column 2nd<br/>Your text text text<br/>Other text text and something other text</div>
</div>
```